# Server is not starting nor is answering to fetch call

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying to set-up a server using `express`. The reason is that I will have to inquire an API provider [AIS Hub](https://www.aishub.net/api) for latitude and longitude coordinates of a vessel. However the request can be execute once per minute. After receiving lat-lon I will locate a vessel on a google-map. 
I have never set up a server and I followed a tutorial I found [here](https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-serve-react-from-same-origin/) to have an example before I implement it in my exercise and followed the instructions on that page.

In the sane folder of my project I `sudo npm install express`

Create a `Server.js` file inside my project folder. The file is very short:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.get('/hey', (req, res) => res.send('Hi Server!'));
app.listen(8080);
```

Now on the same folder I access `package.json` and add `"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"`. 
According to the documentation this:

> This tells React to proxy API requests to the Node.js server built
>   with Express.

So my `package.json` looks like:

```
{
    "name": "my-project",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
        "contentful": "^7.13.1",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "express-generator": "^4.16.1",
        "google-map-react": "^1.1.5",
        "react": "^16.12.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
        "react-icons": "^3.8.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
        "react-scripts": "3.3.0",
        "react-select": "^3.0.8",
        "reactstrap": "^8.4.0",
        "styled-components": "^5.0.0",
        "proxy": "http://localhost:8080"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [ ">0.2%", "not dead", "not op_mini all" ],
        "development": [ "last 1 chrome version", "last 1 firefox version", "last 1 safari version" ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "standard": "^14.3.1"
    }
}
```

Now the documentation says:

> Now run this Node process using node server.js. In another window you
>   start the CRA app using npm start.

Because I have everything in the same folder and I `sudo npm install express` as explained I don't need (I think) to open a second window.

Therefore I launch `sudo npm start` and the browser opens on port 3000 (by default).
From here I open the development tools as explained below:

1) Open Development Tools:

[image: dev-tools]

2) run the command `fetch('/hey')`, so from the Console tab I do that:

[image: fetch]

3) I go to the network panel as explained and should be able to see the response `Hi Server!` but I don't see it, below a couple of print screen:

[image: network1]

And after clicking on `hey` I access the following print screen. Status seems `Ok` but I don't see any message confirming that the server is actually active:

[image: netweork2]

**What I tried so far**:

I tried different combination of starting and shutting down the `localhost:3000`.

I tried to fetch the message several times but still the request seemed to be pending despite after going to the network panel the status again seems to be ok.

I am confused about what to do.
Thanks for shedding light on a possible solution to this problem.

Comment: 1. You've added the `proxy` option to the dependencies, but it needs to go in the top level 2. you do need a second window and run `node Server.js` in it or your express server will never start in the first place

Comment: @ChrisG, thanks for reading the question. So `proxy` should go like after 'version' for example?

Comment: If also I open another terminal and go the the project folder and :`sudo run node Server.js` it says command not found.

Comment: Yes, anywhere on the top level is fine. The command should be `node Server.js` or `sudo node Server.js`.

Comment: Perfect! it is working! Thank you very much for your help. If you could post the answer I will accept it as correct answer. Thanks again :)